# Hide a <div> without a specified string

Tags: javascript, css, search, html

So, to put this as simply as I can..
I have multiple divs with text in them as shown:

```
<div id=1 style="position:relative"><font color=color>Hello Hello</font></div>
<div id=2 style="position:relative"><font color=color>Hello Goodbye</font></div>
<div id=3 style="position:relative"><font color=color>Goodbye Goodbye</font></div>
```

I would like to have a search box somewhere on my page that I can input strings into, for example: "Hello" hides the last div, "Hello Hello" hides the last two divs, "Hello Goodbye" hides the first and last, and "Goodbye Goodbye" hides the first two divs. The input does not have to be case sensative, but I'd prefer the order you input the strings to matter.

Thanks in advance!
-Starletts

PS: I'd prefer to stay out of JQuery if possible.

Comment: @adeneo It's an example, I didn't want to just include a random color. Also, though I'm not one to judge, why even post on this thread if you don't plan to even help at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="my_input">
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('my_input').addEventListener('keyup', function () {
    var search_for = this.value;
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(divs, function (div) {
       if (search_for && div.textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(search_for.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
           div.style.display = 'none'; // to hide
       }
       else {
           div.style.display = 'block';
       }
    });
});​
```

Comment: How would I get the "hello" in "var search_for = 'hello';" to get replaced by whatever string I put into the <input> field? I need this to update live. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, thought you already had a way of getting that. I've updated my code to reflect that requirement.

Comment: Updated it to use array prototype call (since an element set is not an array) and also verified that input has a value (which prevents everything from hiding when field is blank)

Comment: Note that that will also clear as you type, but do you need it to be an exact match of the div content?

Comment: No, this is perfect. Thank you!

Comment: Just one issue, if I replace getElementsByTag with getElementbyId('divid') and give all the divs I want to search that one id, the text I input seems to do nothing, is there a reason behind that?

Comment: You can't give multiple elements the same ID. Use `class="foo"` instead with `getElementsByClassName('foo')`

Answer (score 1):

In pure *W3C specification*:

```
var forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;    

document.getElementById('inputID').addEventListener('keyup', function( event ) {
    forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('div'), function( div ) {
        if( div.textContent.split(/\s+/).indexOf( event.target.value ) > -1 ) {
            div.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            div.style.display = 'block';
        }
    });
}, false);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FA2nj/

Comment: One of those conditions should set the display to something other than none. Otherwise looks good

Comment: Copy paste error, you are hiding them in both cases! And you probably should set it to `.display=""` and not block.

Comment: I have tested this with:
    <input type='text' id=1>
and have replaced the #inputID with "1", though it still doesn't seem to work. I'm probably doing something wrong, as I tend to do. Do you mind pointing out what it might be?
Thanks

Comment: IDs, like classes, can't begin with a digit. Also, add quotes around the ID

Comment: I have followed your instructions, yet no luck. I have: <input type='text' id="search"> and document.addEventListener("search", function( event ), the rest of the code remains unchanged..

Comment: @Starletts: I had some bug in getting the input element. Updated that.

Comment: As I type in text, all the divs dissapear, including the parent one. After typing in an entire string, a div still does not appear.

Comment: @Starletts: see my demo. There is still the quirk that you actually need to split the string in the input field aswell by whitespace (and re-loop over that too), but you should get the idea.

Comment: The divs in the demo do not disappear as I type, but when I finish typing an entire string, it does the opposite by hiding what should be shown and showing what should be hidden. Also, searching "Hello world" ends up doing nothing.. :L

Comment: @Starletts: as I mentioned, you need to split the input string also *as word* and loop-check each word. If you need to revert the logic, just do it. Its only a very small step to get there.

Comment: Thanks, also if you don't mind, is there a way to get it to search with only part of a word, and also search entire strings including spaces? Thanks